# What happens when I connect my TV to a phono input on my receiver?

Tags: troubleshooting

I connected a recent LG TV's 3.5 mini jack to the phono input on an old Marantz receiver by mistake via a mini jack to RCA splitter.

I know I'm not supposed to connect anything other than a turntable to a phono input but I did and I tried to play sound through it. What would have happened? Would it have caused any damage?

Sorry for the beginner question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's improbable that there was any damage, but it could happen.

The signal from a phonograph is weaker (specially with a Moving Coil head) than line level signal.

The phono input of your receiver is optimized for the signal level coming from the phono, so higher level signals could, theoretically, damage the input circuit.

However consumer grade line level signals (as would be coming from the audio output of your TV) are relatively weak signals anyway, so although the input circuit of the receiver could be saturated and produce a distorted sound, it's improbable that there was actual physical damage of the circuit.

Note also that a phono input has a specific filter to compensate for the RIAA equalization that's applied to vinyl recorded music.

[image]

*([image source](http://hometheaterhifi.com/editorial/editor/a-secrets-technical-article63/))*

So even if you achieve (e.g. by controlling the output volume to be rather low) to successfully connect a line level output to a phono input, the resulting audio will be distorted with a serious loss of bass and artificial boosting of the treble frequencies.